# Continuous and residual spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

> **Note:** Please do not give a solution; I would prefer guidance to help me complete the question myself. Thank you.

---

I am having trouble understanding and finding the continuous and residual spectrum. I am working through the following problem:

Let $\alpha = (\alpha_{i})\in\ell^{\infty}$ and let $T_{\alpha}:\ell^{2}\rightarrow\ell^{2}$ with $T_{\alpha}x=(\alpha_{1}x_{1},\alpha_{2}x_{2},\ldots)$.

(i) Compute the spectrum, $\sigma(T_{\alpha})$, of $T_{\alpha}$.

(ii) Identify the point spectrum, $\sigma_{p}(T_{\alpha})$, the continuous spectrum, $\sigma_{c}(T_{\alpha})$, and the residual spectrum, $\sigma_{r}(T_{\alpha})$, of $T_{\alpha}$.

**My Solution**

(i) Suppose $\lambda\in\rho(T_{\alpha})$ (where $\rho(T_{\alpha})$ is the resolvent set of $T_{\alpha}$) then $\lambda I-T_{\alpha}$ is bijective. Hence, for every $y\in\ell^{2}$ $\exists ! x\in\ell^{2}$ such that,
\begin{align}
(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})x = y\implies x = (\lambda I-T_{\alpha})^{-1}y,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
x_{n} = \frac{y_{n}}{\lambda - \alpha_{n}},
\end{align}
for each element, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $x\in\ell^{2}$,
\begin{align}
|x|_{2}^{2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{n}|^{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|y_{n}|^{2}}{|\lambda-\alpha_{n}|^{2}}<\infty.
\end{align}
Therefore, if $\lambda\in\overline{\{\alpha_{n}\}}$ then $|x|_{2} = \infty$. Hence $\sigma(T_{\alpha}) = \{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}|\lambda\in\overline{\{\alpha_{n}\}},n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

(ii) Using the definition of point spectrum,
\begin{align}
\sigma_{p}(T_{\alpha}):=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}|\lambda I-T_{\alpha} \text{is not injective}\},
\end{align}
then there exists $x_{1},x_{2}\in\ell^{2}$, with $x_{1}\neq x_{2}$, such that $(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})x_{1} = (\lambda I-T_{\alpha})x_{2}$. This occurs when $|x|_{2}=\infty$, that is, $\lambda = \alpha_{n}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence, $\sigma_{p}(T_{\alpha})=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}|\lambda = \alpha_{n}\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

At this stage I do not know how to continue. Particularly, I don't understand how to use the definitions of continuous and residual spectrum:
\begin{align}
\sigma_{c}(T_{\alpha})&:=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}|\lambda I-T_{\alpha}\text{ is injective, }\overline{\text{im}(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})}=\ell^{2},(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})^{-1}\text{ is unbounded}\},\\
\sigma_{r}(T_{\alpha})&:=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}|\lambda I-T_{\alpha}\text{ is injective, }\overline{\text{im}(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})}\neq\ell^{2}\}
\end{align}

**Finding continuous and residual spectrum**

Assume $\overline{\text{im}(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})}\neq\ell^{2}$ then $\text{im}(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})^{\perp}\neq\{0\}$. Hence there is $y\in\text{im}(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})^{\perp}$, $y\neq 0$, such that,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\lambda x_{n}-\alpha_{n}x_{n})y_{n} = 0,
\end{align}
for all $x\in\overline{\text{im}(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})}$. This implies $\lambda=\alpha_{n}$ for each $n^{\text{th}}$ element of $x$, which is impossible. Otherwise, $x=0$, however this contradicts our assumption that holds for all $x\in\overline{\text{im}(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})}$. Hence by contradiction, $\overline{\text{im}(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})}=\ell^{2}$ and $\text{im}(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})^{\perp}=\{0\}$. Therefore, $\sigma_{r}(T_{\alpha})=\emptyset$.

By above $(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})$ has trivial kernel and hence injective. Given $\lambda\in\sigma_{c}(T_{\alpha})$ we need $(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})^{-1}$ unbounded. From above this implies,
\begin{align}
|x|_{2}^{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|y_{n}|^{2}}{|\lambda-\alpha_{n}|^{2}}\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align}
Hence, for all $\epsilon>0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $n>N$,
\begin{align}
|\lambda-\alpha_{n}|<\epsilon.
\end{align}
Now $(\alpha_{n})\in\ell^{\infty}$ so they are uniformly bounded. Taking $\lambda=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|\alpha_{n}|$ we satisfy the criteria and hence $(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})^{-1}$ is unbounded.

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\sigma_{p}(T_{\alpha}) &= \{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}|\lambda=\alpha_{n}\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb{N}\},\\
\sigma_{c}(T_{\alpha}) &= \{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}|\lambda = \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|\alpha_{n}|\},\\
\sigma_{r}(T_{\alpha}) &= \emptyset.
\end{align}

Comment: How did you go from\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\lambda x_{n}-\alpha_{n}x_{n})y_{n} = 0,
\end{align} to concluding that $\lambda=\alpha_n$ for all $n$ in your argument?

Comment: I am working under the assumption $y\neq 0$. So in order for the sum on the left to be zero either $\lambda =\alpha_{n}$ for every $n$ or $x=0$. Both cases are not possible.

Comment: Your conclusion that $\lambda=\alpha_x$ for all $n$ is not true. You could have $y_n=0$ for all but one $n$ and $\lambda=\alpha_n$ for the other $n$. And what would that look like?

Comment: Ah ok. I see. That however, would be in the point spectrum, and so not part of the residual.

Comment: I was just pointing out that your conclusion was not correct.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Sorry my previous comment was meant to be a follow up question. So including that case, I would still obtain the same result as above, yes?

Answer (score 1):

A quick overview might be helpful, even though it does not really fit your requirement for an answer.

$T_{\alpha}$ is a bounded normal operator. That rules out all but continuous and point spectrum. Every $\alpha_j$ is in the point spectrum of $T_{\alpha}$, which is easily demonstrated by showing $T_{\alpha}e_n = \alpha_n e_n$ where
$$
   e_n=\{0,0,\cdots,1,0,0,\cdots\},
$$
and where $1$ is in the $n$-th position. Every cluster point of the set $\{ \alpha_n \}$ that is not in the set of eigenvalues is in the continuous spectrum, which is the approximate point spectrum.

Comment: Why does $T_{\alpha}$ bounded rule out residual spectrum? Also, what do you mean by cluster point? Is this an accumulation point? EDIT: If we are talking about accumulation points, should we also be careful not include those points which are equal to an $\alpha_{n}$?

Comment: "Bounded" doesn't rule out residual spectrum, but "bounded normal" does.

Comment: I have never heard of the term "bounded normal", what does this mean?

Comment: @Jack : If $\alpha$ is a point of accumulation of eigenvalues, then it could be an eigenvalue if it is one of the $\alpha_n$ or it might not be. If the point of accumulation of eigenvalues is not an eigenvalue of your operator, then $(\alpha I-T)$ will not have a bounded inverse.

Comment: I understand now. Could you please make sure my argument for the residual being empty is good?

Answer (score 0):

$\lambda \in \sigma_r(T_{\alpha})$ iff  $\lambda I-T_{\alpha}$ is injective and there is  a non zero element $y$ orthogonal to $im(\lambda I-T_{\alpha})$  which means $\sum (\lambda x_i-\alpha_i x_i) y_i=0$ for all $x \in \ell^{2}$. It should be easy to determine when this happens. For the continuous spectrum see what it means to have $\|\lambda I-T_{\alpha}(x)\|^{2}\geq C \|x\|^{2}$ for some $C>0$.

Comment: Could you please clarify the orthogonality argument for the residual spectrum?

Comment: @Jack A linear subspace is dense iff its orthogonal complement is $\{0\}$. This leads to the equation $\sum (\lambda x_i-\alpha_ix_i)y_i=0$ for all $x$. Take basis vectors $e_j$ for $x$ to see that $(\lambda -\alpha_i)y_i=0$ for all $i$. When does this happen for some $y \neq 0$?

Comment: I am still confused. Would this mean $\lambda = (\alpha_{i})$?

Comment: Some $y_i \neq 0$ so $\lambda =\alpha_i$ for this $i$. But remember to check if $\lambda I -T_{\alpha}$ is injective for this $\lambda$.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly, $\lambda I-T_{\alpha}$ will not be injective. In fact it will be the zero map?

Comment: It is not the zero map. Only the $i-$th coordinate in the image is $0$, so we don't get injectivity. Residual spectrum is therefore empty.

Comment: Is this not the same as the point spectrum?

Comment: Also this doesn't mean that the orthogonal complement of the image is $\{0\}$ because the inner product $((\lambda I-T_{\alpha})x|y)\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I will work through it and post an amended solution tomorrow. In the meantime could you please take a look at another question of mine https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202698/spectrum-of-product-of-continuous-linear-operators.

Comment: I have given the proof another go. If you don't mind could you please check my work. Thank you.